# Daemon gets controlling interface and receives SIGHUP after opening ttyACM0

Tags: javascript, node.js, daemon, pm2, tty

I'm reading handheld scanner in my NodeJS program as a background service. This is handled by the pm2 framwork.

```
ion@ion:~$ pm2 --version
2.10.4
ion@ion:~$ node -v
v8.9.4
ion@ion:~$ cat /etc/debian_version 
9.4
ion@ion:~$ uname -r
4.9.0-6-amd64
```

Sometimes I noticed that the program restarted when i detached the scanner from the pc. Pm2 made a log message that it was in due to a SIGHUP. I had a look on the process list. When the process was started and no scanner is opened the process 616 looks like this:

```
ion@ion:~$ ps -e | grep node
  601  ?        00:00:02 node /home/ion/
  7420 ?        00:00:19 node /mnt/data/
```

When the scanner was attached it was successfully registered as the /dev/ttyACM0 device and opened by my program. Then it got the controlling interface of the process:

```
ion@ion:~$ sudo dmesg | tail
[   12.341225] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready
[  427.725859] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  427.874564] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05f9, idProduct=4204
[  427.874572] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  427.874638] usb 1-2: Product: Handheld Barcode Scanner
[  427.874642] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Datalogic ADC, Inc.
[  427.874646] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: S/N E17A28236
[  427.901364] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[  427.902747] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[  427.902752] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
ion@ion:~$ ps -e | grep node
  601  ?        00:00:02 node /home/ion/
  7420 ttyACM0  00:00:26 node /mnt/data/
```

Is that a normal and expected behavior? I tried to ensure this in my program. I opened the device in the following way:

```
  openDev(dev) {

    console.log("Opening scanner " + devdir + dev);

    var inp = fs.createReadStream(devdir + dev);

    ...
```

When I added a return bevor the createReadStream call the device dows not become the controlling terminal. When I added a return directly after the createReadStream call the device does become the controlling terminal. When i now detach the scanner from usb pm2 logs the following message and my program will restart.

```
PM2        | App [server] with id [1] and pid [7420], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGHUP]
PM2        | Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:server id:1
PM2        | App name:server id:1 online
```

Can anybody help my why the scanner gets controlling interface of my process? I had the problem that my program got an SIGINT when i scanned, too (but i can't reproduce this now).

Should i use another function to open the device?

Answer (score 0):

After digging in the deep for some days and a lot of sleepless nights, i found out that this is just a normal behavior. A process without controlling terminal can acquire this, when it opens a tty device.

My solution was to have a look at the **createReadStream** function and saw that there could be supplied some flags (rw, r, a+, ...). Nevertheless there can be a lot of more flags be supplied. One of this is the solution. I had a look on the manpage for **open**:

```
   O_NOCTTY
          If pathname refers to a terminal device—see tty(4)—it will not become the process's con‐
          trolling terminal even if the process does not have one.
```

I modified the opening of the display in the following way:

```
var inp = fs.createReadStream(DEVDIR + dev, {
  flags: fs.constants.O_NOCTTY
});
```

An it works!